# How to call method on custom control via ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

I am using the MVVM pattern in my project. It uwas using code-behind.

The issue that I'm having is: Included in my project I have a page transition control that I downloaded from [Simple WPF Page transitions](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/197132/Simple-WPF-Page-Transitions).

It worked great in code-behind, the xaml as follows:

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="False">
    <pageTransitions:PageTransition Name="pageTransitionControl" Margin="0" TransitionType="GrowAndFade" />
</Grid>
```

with this in the window tag:

```
xmlns:pageTransitions="clr-namespace:WpfPageTransitions;assembly=WpfPageTransitions"
```

In the code-behind I just ran:

```
mast.Page mp = new mast.Page();
pageTransitionControl.ShowPage(mp);
```

When I do the below code-behind, it unloads the current page (mp) and loads the new one (dp)

```
dist.Page dp = new dist.Page();
pageTransitionControl.ShowPage(dp);
```

Above "mp" and "dp" are new instances of a UserControl (page). pageTransitionControl is the name of the transition control in the xaml.

Now I would like to get it to run via the ViewModel, without communicating with the view as it is doing above, how can I go about this?

Comment: Seems to me that control doesn't support an MVVM scenario. You're better off using the `TransitionPresenter` from the [WPF Bag of Tricks](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/bot), which has the same animated transitions feature, but it is much more MVVM friendly.

Comment: Yes after thinking about it, the project doesn't provide MVVM. I will check out the bag of tricks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, the `PageTransition` control would provide a way for you to set the current page via binding. Assuming that it does not provide a way of doing that, then there are a number of ways of achieving this.

Here are three suggestions, in order of "niceness" (in my opinion).

1. You can create a new page transition control which either is a wrapper for `PageTransition` or inherits it. And then add a `DependecyProperty` for the current page to that class which you can bind to, catch the dependecy property change event and call `ShowPage`.
2. Write a class inhering `FrameworkElement` or `DependencyObject`, depending on usage, which can bind to a page and to the `PageTransition` control. This class is then responsible for calling `ShowPage` on the bound `PageTransition` control when the current page changes.
3. Bind the `PageTransition` control to a property on your model and have code in the model access the control via that property.

Example:

```
public class MyPageTransition : ContentControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentPageProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "CurrentPage", 
            typeof(object), 
            typeof(MyPageTransition), 
            new PropertyMetadata(DependencyPropertyChanged));

    public ContentControl()
    {
        this.Content = this.pageTransition;
    }

    public object CurrentPage
    {
        get { return GetValue(CurrentPageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CurrentPageProperty, value); }
    }

    protected static void DependencyPropertyChanged(
        DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Property == CurrentPageProperty)
        {
            this.pageTransition.ShowPage(CurrentPage);
        }
    }

    private PageTransition pageTransition = new PageTransition();
}
```

Comment: I think I'll go for the nicest, No.1. Where would I look for how to start designing this control?